# Kubernetes deny commnunications between pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have two deployments in kubernetes on Azure both with three replicas. Both deployments use `oauth2 reverse proxy` for external users/requests authentication. The manifest file for both deployments looks like the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice1
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: my-pod-identity-binding
spec:
  replicas: 3
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 1800
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myservice1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice1
        aadpodidbinding: my-pod-identity-binding
      annotations:
        aadpodidbinding.k8s.io/userAssignedMSIClientID: pod-id-client-id
        aadpodidbinding.k8s.io/subscriptionID: my-subscription-id
        aadpodidbinding.k8s.io/resourceGroup: my-resource-group
        aadpodidbinding.k8s.io/useMSI: 'true'
        aadpodidbinding.k8s.io/clientID: pod-id-client-id
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
      containers:
        - name: myservice1
          image: mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/myservice1:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 2
            timeoutSeconds: 60
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 1
            httpGet:
              host:
              scheme: HTTP
              path: /healthcheck
              port: 5000
              httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: http://127.0.0.1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "4G"
              cpu: "2"
            limits:
              memory: "8G"
              cpu: "4"
          env:
          - name: MESSAGE
            value: Hello from the external app!!
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: myservice1
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://myservice1.com/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://myservice1.com/oauth2/start?rd=https://myservice1.com/oauth2/callback"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s  
  name: myservice1-external
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservice1.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice1
            port:
              number: 80
```

Now, I want to restrict the communication between the pods in two ways:

1. Intra-deployments: I want to deny any communication between the 3 pods of each deployments internally; meaning that all 3 pods can and must only communicate with their corresponding proxy (Ingress part of the manifest)
2. Inter-deployments: I want to deny any communications between any two pods belonging to two deployments; meaning that if for example pod1 from deployment1 tries lets say to ping or send http request to pod2 from deployment2; this will be denied.
3. Allow requests throw proxies: the only requests that are allowed to enter must go through the correspoding deployment's proxy.

How to implement the manifest for the netwrok policy that achieves these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of NetworkPolicies and reference the Policy in your ingress configuration like below:-

**My networkpolicy.yml:-**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

I applied it in my Azure Kubernetes like below:-

```bash
kubectl apply -f networkpolicy.yml
kubectl get networkpolicies
```

[image]

[image]

Then use the below yml file to reference the NetworkPolicy in the ingress settings:-

**ingress.yml:-**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-access
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-to-backends
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ingress: "true"
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
```

[image]